# how to retrive shared preferences from another class without activity ANDROID

Tags: android

```
package com.example.win7.simpleloginapp;



public class ServerRequest  {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS =  "ekinidris.site40.net";

final static String TAG_USER = "user";
JSONArray user;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
// Create object of SharedPreferences.
SharedPreferences sharedPref1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
public ServerRequest(Context context) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Processing..");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
}

public void storeUserDataInBackground(user user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
    progressDialog.show();
    new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();
}

public void fetchUserDataInBackground(user user, GetUserCallback callBack) {
    progressDialog.show();
    new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, callBack).execute();
}






public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, user> {
    user user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected user doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));


        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://mysyshcms.cloudapp.net:1005/fetchUserData.php");

        user returnedUser = null;
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if(jObject.length()==0)
            {
                returnedUser = null;

            }
            else
            {



                String Name1 = jObject.getString("Name");


                //now get Editor
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref1.edit();
                //put your value
                editor.putString("username", Name1);

                //commits your edits
                editor.commit();
                returnedUser = new user(user.username, user.password);

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnedUser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(user returnedUser) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(returnedUser);
        super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
    }
}
```

}

i have `ServerRequest` class which is not an `activity` . In  public class `fetchUserDataAsyncTask` i want to make a shared preferences . this is because i want to pass data that i get from database to another activity (`MainActivity`)

```
public class MainActivity extends  ActionBarActivity  {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#689a92")));
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   SharedPreferences sharedPref1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String userName = sharedPref1.getString("username", "NOT AVAILABLE");
    etUsername.setText(userName);
```

but i keep getting "NOT AVAILABLE" instead of Name1 that i declare in server request . How to solve this ?

Comment: where have u called ServerRequest to store user name in SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u to implement SharedPreferences into your current class. You must at first pass related activity context.

try this :

```
public class ServerRequest {

private Context mContext;
public ServerRequest(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public SharedPreferences getSharedPref(){
    return mContext.getSharedPreferences(mContext.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void storeData(String data) {
    getSharedPref().edit().putString("data", data).apply();
}

public String getData(){
    return getSharedPref().getString("data", "");
}

}
```

Now, on your any classes. You can read back the data by calling

```
ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(getActivity());
Log.d("","The value is : " + serverRequest.getData());
```

Comment: kenapa getActivity utk read data dia error ? ada kene declare apa apa ke ?

Answer (score 0):

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) is used for default SharedPreferences file that is used by the preference framework.

If you want to save SharedPreferences inside your app then you need to use SharedPreferences interface. To use it you'll need the context of the Activity.

The following snippet shows you how to save data to SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferecnes("Shared_PREF_NAME, Contextt.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("key", 100);
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve use this:

```
sharedPreferences.getInt("key", 0);
```

For more info, visit following links:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Comment: The preference framework that I have mentioned above is used for settings inside your app

Comment: i dont quite understand how to use the code you give me ?

Comment: Remove your PreferenceManager.SharedPreferences and use the SharedPreference interface in place of it.

Comment: The implementation of both is almost the same

Comment: on the server request and main activity is it ?

Comment: Yes. My code is just an example of how to use the interface. So, use your shared preference name in the getSharedPreference() method.

Comment: If you don't have a shared preference name, you can use any name. You'll just need to use it again when you either add or remove any data from the SharedPreferences

Comment: Oh, I added one extra t in the last. Its "Context".

Comment: And please note, my code is just an example explaining you how to use SharedPreferences. Its not the final code for your app. You'll need to create the final code yourself by understanding how its done through my code.

Comment: still error too . but my server request is not activity . can i still do the shared preferences ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly save data preference in your onPostExecute method of your fetchUserDataAsyncTask class and you can access that,
like below.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPref1.edit().putString("username",""+username).commit();
```